# How to filter out only relevant Media files in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to fetch all the music files in my phone:

For this I'm using:

```
String[] STAR = {"*"};

Uri allExternalSongUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";



Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(allExternalSongUri, STAR, selection, null, null);
if(cursor != null){
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            String songName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
            Log.i("name", songName);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

But above code, apart from getting music files, is also fetching some additional unnecessary files like *sound_screen_on.mp3* (which is installed & used by some other app).

Issue is my native android music player does not list & plays these unnecessary files.

How can I filter files like these.

Comment: I dont think its possible, because lots of app uses *.mp3 to play the background effect sounds. Even some Ringtone app uses *.mp3 file as ringtone. May be you can fetch *.mp3 with a length greater than 1 min which can reduce the unwanted *.mp3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can filter using [MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.html#DURATION) class.That will return lots of value of Audio file and you can use it.

```
musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            proj, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">= 60000", null, null);
```

- Filter by [Duration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.html#DURATION) - The duration of the audio file, in ms
- Filter by [Type-Music](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.html#IS_MUSIC) -Non-zero if the audio file is music
- Filter by [Type-RingTone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.html#IS_RINGTONE) - Non-zero if the audio file may be a ringtone
- Filter by [Type-Alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.html#IS_ALARM) - Non-zero if the audio file may be an alarm

[Check for more reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242566/filtering-songs-from-other-music-files-android)

Comment: good summary! upvoted!  i dont think the duration is reliable (a really short song is still a song), but the other 3 columns are very usefull

Comment: @chintan khetiya, if i want to call multiple query in a single query then is it possible? As like calling Genre names that have songs in it

Comment: Please also refer my question here if you can answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497983/fetch-genre-name-list-which-have-songs-in-it

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Genres.html you can use this

Comment: if I have `file, path or uri` of some file, how to check if this file is audio? so I want to check just specific file (and not using method with extension equal like .mp3, but with MediaStore)

Comment: How to have both Type-Music and Duration in selection?  I tried selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0" + " WHERE " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">=" + 60000; but it doesn't work?

Comment: Nvm, i figured it out, i had to change WHERE to AND

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the above methods suggested by others, in the case where column is not reliable from the db, you can always use MediaMetadataRetriever to get the information you want after the first filtering from the db.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html

This is of course slower than getting existing information from the media db, but it will give you author/album/duration etc other information and you can do as custom filter as you can get with the file list that you get from the ContentProvider.

Answer (score 1):

Using your same code, i dont get any undesired file.

Usually that files are marked to be ignored, so probably the media scanner did something wrong or the index is not updated in your system.

Sounds, images and other media files that are meant to be used by one app or by the system, are marked to be ignored simply by adding a file called ".nomedia" in the same directory. As you can read in the docs of the [MediaStore provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html)

> public static final String MEDIA_IGNORE_FILENAME
>
> Added in API level 9 Name of the file signaling the media scanner to
>   ignore media in the containing directory and its subdirectories.
>   Developers should use this to avoid application graphics showing up in
>   the Gallery and likewise prevent application sounds and music from
>   showing up in the Music app.
>
> Constant Value: ".nomedia"

So, besides of the advices from chintan khetiya, that are great, probably you can consider that there are some files marked to be ignored, that are not actually being ignored, and check it by yourself.

Simply, when you iterating the cursor, for every file, just check if in the same directory there is a file called like the value of `MediaStore.MEDIA_IGNORE_FILENAME` or the hardcoded `.nomedia`

Answer (score 0):

only get the music which the _data is more than a certain value, for example 300kb.