# Fetch Genre name list which have songs in it

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, simplecursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I am fetching Genre list from media content Provider of android using CursorLoder class.
below is my cursor query to fetch the list of Genre.

```
 public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // currently filtering.
        Uri baseUri;
        baseUri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] STAR = { "*" };
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri, STAR, null, null, null );
    }
```

Now, i got all the genre list from the media content provider but the problem with the data i got. I also got the genre name which is created before but right now i don't have song in it.

I only want the genre that have songs in it, not the genre name that dont have songs in it.

Can anyone help me in that?

**UPDATE**

I can able to fetch all the Genre and its Song using below code...

```
private void getGenresList() {

        //-------------------------------------

        int index;
        long genreId;
        int count;
        Uri uri;
        Cursor genrecursor;
        Cursor tempcursor;
        String[] proj1 = {MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID};   
        String[] proj2={MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};

         genrecursor=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj1,null, null, null);
         if(genrecursor.moveToFirst())
         {
             do{
                index = genrecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME);            
                System.out.println("GENRE NAME: "+genrecursor.getString(index));
                System.out.println("======================================");

                index = genrecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID);             
                genreId=Long.parseLong(genrecursor.getString(index));
                uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri("external", genreId);

                tempcursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, proj2, null,null,null);
                System.out.println("Total Songs: "+tempcursor.getCount());
                if(tempcursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do{
                        index=tempcursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                        System.out.println("    Song Name: "+tempcursor.getString(index));

                    }while(tempcursor.moveToNext());
                }
                System.out.println("======================================");
             }while(genrecursor.moveToNext());       
         }


        //-------------------------------------

    }
```

But, i must have to use two query, one for fetching all the genre and second for filter data with the Genre which have songs. Even i would like to use that in the CursorLoader so i am wonder wonder about how to do that.

Hope you got proper idea what i want with this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like there is no other method to achieve this so i have just do like below... 
With below update i can able to get the Genre list which only have songs in it. The genre list which don't have songs are filtered out.

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        Uri baseUri;
        if (mCurFilter != null) {
            baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    Uri.encode(mCurFilter));
        } else {
            baseUri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }

        String[] STAR = { MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME };


        String query = " _id in (select genre_id from audio_genres_map where audio_id in (select _id from audio_meta where is_music != 0))" ;

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, STAR, query,
                null, null);

    }
```

In above code i have join the genre table with audio table. with this way i am able to fetch, whether that Genre have songs or not. So now i have only that genre which have songs in it.

Hope this will help others also.

Enjoy Coding... :)

Comment: Geez I hate the fact that we have go through all the trouble of filtering out genres that do not have tracks. What's the point of polluting MediaStore with orphan genres in the first place?

Comment: What is mCurFilter ?

Comment: @jack please refer this: http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/net/Uri.html#withAppendedPath(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String)

Comment: Where mCurFilter is initialized ?