# How to filter ringtone, alarm and relevant media files in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-cursor, mediastore

I am trying to retrieve music file from the android INTERNAL STORAGE URI but I am gettting the alarm and ringtones also  I came to know about filtering [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707954/how-to-filter-out-only-relevant-media-files-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1) .So i tried to set the duration equal to 30sec then also I am getting some alarm file .I can not set multiple condition this is what I tried

```
  String[] proj2 = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE};// Can include more data for more details and check it.
     String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">=30000";
    Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj2, selection,null, null);
```

I tried to select by ringtone and is_music but then also i am getting some alarm files .So what should i try to filter all the ringtones ,alarm and other such inbuilt files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hei man , I look up your code . Once I have faced the same problem while doing media Query with  `Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj2, selection,null, null);`

but Everything you did is perfect You just need to Query through `Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;`

so your whole content resolver and query should be like this

```
String[] proj2 = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE};// Can include more data for more details and check it.
 String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">=30000";
Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj2, selection,null, null);
```

Comment: then i will not able to short the songs according to the name

Comment: I tried this but it still not working Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj2, selection,null, null);

Comment: I followed this post for my problem [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764)

Comment: I follow this link https://github.com/Cleveroad/MusicBobber/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/cleveroad/audiowidget/example/MusicLoader.java